# How to save image path/image to database where i have my images in my drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have store all my images at the drawable folder in my app. How do i store the path of the image in my drawable folder to database?

```
db.addWords(new Words(1,"apple","applepathdrawable" ,1));
```

How do you put in that "applepathdrawable"?

Sorry it's my first time using database on android. Currently using SQLiteDatabase..

Comment: Take some help from this [link](http://androhub.com/android-sqlite-database/).

Comment: You just get the resource id of the drawable and store that integer in database. Retrieve the drawable resource id and populate the image with the resource id when ever it is required.

Comment: As far as I know, ID can change from one compilation to others, can't it?

Comment: As @JuanAguilarGuisado id can change from one compilation to other. BTW, why do you need to save those ids in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you to save the name of your resource as a plain String and get the ID dinamically using a method like this:

```
public static Integer getImageId(String name, Context context) {
    if (name == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        }
    }
```

This sample is for your drawable folder.

For instance, if your want to get the ID for your drawable "apple.png", store in your DB "apple" and give this String as input to your method getImageId avobe defined.

I hope this would help you!

Comment: sorry i dont really get it.. er.. what's the context?? does this mean i don't store my image in database? but i wanna link it to database.. like i wanna have id,name,date,photo how can i put a photo inside database? o.o sorry i too noob..

Comment: If you want to load your images dinamically, and you put all of them in your drawable folder, you only have to store a name, or an id to get them. You don't have to store your images in your database. Context is a base concept of Android. Context are, for instance, Activities. Is an input parameter which makes you able to get your current id dinnamically.

Comment: Although it is the only answer right now, please mark it as the correct one in case it is.